$x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\land$ $x$ $\in$ $B$ $\iff$ $x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\setminus $ $B$.
From Solution 25, case 2 https://www.inchmeal.io/htpi/ch-3/sec-3.5.html, it suggests $x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\land$ $x$ $\in$$B$ $\iff$ $x$ $\notin$ $A$$\setminus $$B$
. Is this correct?  Should it not be $$x \notin A\backslash B \Leftrightarrow \neg (x \in A \: \wedge \: x \notin B) \Leftrightarrow (\neg(x \in A) \: \vee \: \neg(x \notin B)) \Leftrightarrow (x \notin A \: \vee \: x \in B).$$

Soln 25, Case 3 assumes that $x\in A\setminus C$, $x\notin B$, and $x\notin C$. And it tries to show an implication only. Where does it suggest what you write its does?

@HagenvonEitzen sorry I meant case 2. I have edited my question.

I don't see your claim being made in Soln25 case 2.

That claim is not there in the whole of Soln25 , @SassatelliGiulio , there may be some mix-up.

@SassatelliGiulio Under case 2, it says $x$ $\in$ $C$ $\land$ $x$ $\notin$ A $\land$ $x$ $\in$ $B$. Since $x$ $\notin$ $A$, it follows $x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\setminus$$B$. Could I have misinterpreted it?

And how did you make $(x\notin A\land x\in B)\Leftrightarrow x\notin A\setminus B$ out of that?

@Darren So the property they actually use is $x\notin A\implies x\notin A\setminus B$. And that is clear from $A\setminus B\subseteq A$

This is a very simple drawing of $x \notin A / B$, while $x \notin A \land x \in B$ is not true:

Small remark: you can put entire formulae in MathJax, no need to put every single thing between dollar-signs:
$x$ $\notin$ $A$

Looks like: $x$ $\notin$ $A$
$x \notin A$

... also looks like: $x \notin A$

The equivalence in the title is not true. Take $A$ and $B$ as the empty set. Then $x \in B$ is false, so the left hand side is false. But $A \setminus B$ is also the empty set, so the right side is true.
